# If either needle in haystack

Tags: python

I know I can do:

```
if 'hello' in 'hello world':
```

What if I have a several needles like ('.css', '.js', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.com') and I want to check if either of these is in a string.

(note: `endswith` won't do it in this case, they may not be suffixes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) useful:

```
haystack = 'hello world'
needles = ['.css', '.js', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.com']
if any(needle in haystack for needle in needles):
    pass  # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for needle in ['.css', '.js', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.com']:
  if needle in haystack:
    return 'found'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to "multi-match":

```
import re
pat = r'(\.css|\.js|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.com)'
files = ['file.css', 'file.exe', 'file.js', 'file.bat']
for f in files:
    if re.findall(pat, f):
        print f
```

**OUTPUT**

```
file.css
file.js
```

Notice that this solution enables you to run on arbitrary different number of file-names and compare it against multiple different extensions!